# Multiprocessing in Python: impossible to get back my results (get()) (happens rarely)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use Multiprocessing in Python in order to do several requests to a database (and other stuff):

```
po = multiprocessing.Pool()
for element in setOfElements:
    results.append(po.apply_async(myDBRequestModule, (element, other stuff...)))                    
po.close()
po.join()
for r in results:
    newSet.add(r.get())
```

myDBRequestModule returns an object I defined, made of a list and two numbers. I redefined the hash function, in order to define what I mean by equality in my sets of these objects:

```
class myObject:
    def __init__(self, aList, aNumber, anotherNumber):
        self.list = aList
        self.number1 = aNumber
        self.number2 = anotherNumber
    def __hash__(self):
        # turn elements of list into a string, in order to hash the string
        hash_text = ""
        for element in self.list:
            hash_text += str(element.x.id) # I use the ID of the element of my list...
        return hash(hash_text)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self_hash_text = ""
        other_hash_text = ""
        for element in self.list:
            self_hash_text += str(element.x.id)
        for element in other.listDest:
            other_hash_text += str(element.x.id)
        return self_hash_text == other_hash_text
```

And in most cases it works as it should. Twice, for no known reason and in exactly the same context, I had a bug:

```
newSet.add(r.get())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

It comes from the get method (last line):

```
def get(self, timeout=None):
    self.wait(timeout)
    if not self._ready:
        raise TimeoutError
    if self._success:
        return self._value
    else:
        raise self._value
```

Since I had this mistake only once and it disappeared, I decided to give up earlier, but it created a second problem recently, and I really don't know how to fight this bug.
In particular, it's difficult for me to tell why it happens almost never, and usually works perfectly fine.

Comment: Probably unreleated, but `raise TimeoutError` should be `raise TimeoutError()`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me @Willy, I don't know why it's like this, I'll do it for this one for sure.

Comment: the Error seems to be in myDBRequestModule. `raise self._value` raises the error from the other side but drops the traceback.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, it's really written `raise TimeoutError`, without `()`. But I didn't change anything in this file, it is as it was when I installed it.

Comment: The exception occurred in the call to `myDBRequestModule(element, other stuff...)` in a subprocess. Multiprocessing caught the exception, sent it to the main process and raised it again in `get`. Can you show the code of myDBRequestModule?

Comment: MyDBRequestModule was taking one existing object as argument (`MyDBRequestModule(anExistingObjectThatIsModifiedByTheModule)`), and modifying it: `anExistingObjectThatIsModifiedByTheModule.oneAttributeReference = 42`. There were between 50 and 200 processes running together, and sometimes different processes where trying to modify the object at the same time. I think this was the problem. Sorry for not being precise enough in the question, and thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` is not the issue here.

You have not given us the right code to diagnose the issue.  At some point you have assigned a caught exception to `self._value`.  That is where the error is occurring.  Look at everywhere that `self._value` is assigned and you will be on your way to finding this error.

Comment: First, in my class, I created a __str__ method, so when trying to raise an exception, Python will be able to raise the exception and print the object. But it doesn't solve the origin of the problem. In particular, I should find a way to gather information about the bug. Don't you think it's related to multiprocessing? `self._success` is wrong, it means something went wrong in the multiprocessing, no?

Comment: No.  I do not think it is related to multiprocessing.  Just because an error occurs *while using* multiprocessing, does not mean it is *caused by* multiprocessing.  At some point a `TypeError` was assigned to `self._value`.  You then choose to raise `self._value` when `self._success` evaluates to `False`.  The traceback shows only back to where you raise the exception.  Ideally, you would get an exception when you call `get()` on a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult`.  However, it appears that you have caught and suppressed the exception elsewhere.

Comment: OK, I found a mistake in myDBRequestModule(anExistingObjectThatIsModifiedByTheModule): one of the argument is modified in the module, and so this object is modified by several processes. Cannot say if it's the solution, since it very difficult to reproduce the error, but it really looked wrong. Thanks for your help.